# Change of db driver generates error on search in application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I changed database from a MSSQL to a MySQL for my very old project.
I have now a problem with searching in my application.

I have a search form where the user can search by persons name, persons id and by persons address, so when the user search for all persons in a particular city I get this error:

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode  \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'substr' {originalText=substr}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[DOT] DotNode: 'addresses1_.ADDTXT' {propertyName=address,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=address,path=ad0.address,tableAlias=addresses1_,className=com.myproject.core.bean.Address,classAlias=ad0}
       |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: '(addresses1_.ADLNO, addresses1_.PERSONID)' {alias=ad0, className=com.myproject.core.bean.Address, tableAlias=addresses1_}
       |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'address' {originalText=address}
       +-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '1'
       \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '5'
```

the classes for these two:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSONID", columnDefinition = "DECIMAL", precision = 9, scale = 0)
    private int storeID;

    @Column(name = "NAMN", columnDefinition = "CHAR", length=25)
    private String personName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Address> addresses;

    /**getters and setters**/
}


@Entity
@Table(name="PERSONADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private AddressKey addressKey;

    @Column(name="ADDTXT", columnDefinition="CHAR", length=25)
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDTYPE")
    private AddressType addressType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSONID", referencedColumnName="PERSONID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Person person;

    /**getters and setters**/
}


@Embeddable
public class AddressKey implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name="PERSONID", columnDefinition="DECIMAL", precision=9, scale=0, nullable=false)
    private int personID;

    @Column(name="ADLNO", columnDefinition="DECIMAL", precision=5, scale=0, nullable=false)
    private int serialNumber;

    /**getters and setters**/
}
```

**pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>
```

So each person has a set of addresses, each address row has its own post in the database (streetaddress, zipcode, city, phonenumber etc)
The addresses has a key on personID and a serialnumber.
In the database ther is one table for person and one table for address, but there are three classes as you can see.

THe HQL query is

```
select p 
from com.myclass.bean.core.Person p
where ('LONDON' in (
select substr(ad0.address, 1, 6) 
from p.addresses ad0 
where ad0.addressType = 'CITY'))
order by p.personID asc;
```

Following properties in my properties file

```
db.driverClass=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.jdbc.hibernate.default.schema=dbo
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=dbo
```

What does this error mean? And what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Well it looks like you are trying to perform a `substr` on a column that has type `decimal`.  According to my brief reading, in MySQL you can only call it on a string type.  MSSQL is more permissive.

Comment: Could you please explain how you can see that? 
Becuase the query I get does the substring on  address which is a string/char. I'm a bit confused here.
I believed it was the embeddable key that was the issue...?